# Looping data from json using Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a function but I doesn't make it. This function works like that

Input: `changeSetting("a>b>c","hello")`

After that "setting" named value change from `{}` to `{"a":{"b":{"c":"hello"}}}`

If input is `changeSetting("a","hello")` json become `{}` to `{"a":"hello"}`

My last code attempt:

```js
function changeSetting(name,val)  {
  if (name.includes(">")) {
    name = name.split('>')
    let json = {}
    name.map((el,i)=>{
    let last = "" 
    name.filter(el=>!name.slice(i+1).includes(el)).map(el=> {
    if(last!="") {
      json[el] = {}
    }})
    }) 
  }
 }
```

How can we make this ? (Optimization not important but if is it good for me)

Answer (score 0):

```
const changeSetting = (setting, target) => {
  if (setting.length < 2) {
    return {
      [setting]: target
    }
  } else {

    const keys = setting.split('>');

    return keys.reduceRight((acc, curr, i) => {

      console.log(acc);

      if(i === keys.length - 1) {
        return acc = {[curr] : target}    
      }
      
        return acc = { [curr]: acc };
    }, {})

    
  }
}


console.log(changeSetting('a', 'hello'));
console.log(changeSetting('a>b>c', 'hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeSetting(name, value) {
  let result;
  const attributes = name.split(">");
  result = `
{
${attributes
    .map((attribute) => attribute+":")
    .join("{")}"
 ${value}"${"}".repeat(properties.length)}`;
  return result;
}
changeSetting("a>b>c", "hello");
changeSetting("a", "hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to do this, I've commented the snippet

```js
const changeSetting = (name, val) => {
    
    // Split and reverse the name letters
    const nameSplit = name.split('>').reverse();

    // Set up the inner most object
    let newObj = {[nameSplit[0]]:val}

    // Now remove the first letter and recurse through the rest
    nameSplit.slice(1).forEach((el, idx) => newObj = {[el]: newObj});

    console.log(newObj);
}

changeSetting("a>b>c", "hello")
changeSetting("a", "hello")
changeSetting("a>b>c>d>e>f>g", "hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you work with strings - you may try to use JSON like this:

```
function changeSetting(name, val) {
  const keys = name.split(">");
  return JSON.parse(
    [
      "{",
      keys.map((key) => `"${key}"`).join(":{"),
      ":",
      `"${val}"`,
      "}".repeat(keys.length),
    ].join("")
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array by splitting `name` on all `>` with [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), and then [Array.prototype.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) the created array of elements with an object initial value `{}` and adding key value pairs but on the last element the value should be variable `val`.

Code:

```js
const changeSetting = (name, val) => name
  .split('>')
  .reduceRight((a, c, i, arr) => ({ 
    [c]: i === arr.length - 1 ? val : a 
  }), {})

console.log(changeSetting('a>b>c', 'hello'))
console.log(changeSetting('a', 'hello'))
console.log(changeSetting('a>b>c>d>e>f>g', 'hello'))
```